# Are there efficent ways to do bidirectional dimensionality reduction?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, gaussian, dimensions, dimensionality-reduction

Are there any sensible techniques for dimensionality reduction, for example from 20 to 5 dimensions, and then being able (albeit with loss of data) go back from 5 to 20?

Algorithms like t-SNE, PCA, Gaussian Random Projection are great but as far as I can tell there's no easy way to (somewhat) consistently go back from the compressed lower-dimensional data to higher dimensional data.

I am specifically training GPs for candidate generation, and the GPs in question perform better when I am working in lower dimensions. In order to generate a candidate I need to be able to go from the trained model to a new point in the same dimensions as what I give it.

I use a small untrained Neural network (linear layer and and an activation function) that takes higher and outputs lower dimensional data. When I want to go back, I do gradient descent on the input of the net based on the output (which is the lower dimensional data I have). 
This kind of works, but an untrained network is unlikely to be the best technique.

Comment: `no easy way to (somewhat) consistently go back from the compressed lower-dimensional data to higher dimensional data.` Well, you consciously lost information, and now want it to be there for you?

Comment: This is an interesting question which you should probably raise on stats.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com. Essentially the problem is that dimensionality reduction is going to map a manifold (flat or deformed subset of R^n) into a single point. The question is what to consider as the inverse mapping. Apparently any point on the manifold is equally valid, so you have to impose some way of breaking the tie. Are there any points which are invariant under the mapping? Are there points which are more probable than others? Maybe prefer the "smallest" point in a suitable sense? E.g. norm.

Comment: Look into autoencoders.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I am well aware I lose information hence the '(somewhat)' in that sentence, '(albeit with loss of data) ' in the previous sentence, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Independent component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis) could take you there: essentially the reverse of principal component analysis.